# POVM used in proof of Holveo bound

Tags: quantum-mechanics, homework-and-exercises, quantum-information

I'm trying to understand a part of the Holevo bound, as found in Nielsen and Chuang, p. 533.

In an excercise, they write

> Define $U_y$ to be the unitary operator acting on the system $M$ whose
>   action on a basis is $U_y|y' \rangle = |y +y' \rangle$, where addition
>   is done modulo $n+1$. Show that $\{\sqrt{E_y} \otimes U_y\}$ is a set
>   of operation elements defining a trace-preserving quantum operation
>   $\varepsilon$ whose action on states of the form $\sigma \otimes |0
> \rangle \langle 0|$ satisfies $\varepsilon(\sigma \otimes |0 \rangle
> \langle 0|) = \sum_y \sqrt{E_y}\sigma\sqrt{E_y} \otimes |y \rangle\langle y|$.

In the above, $\{ E_y \}$ is a set of POVM elements.

I am able to prove the trace-preserving property, but I am confused about the terminology for the rest of the question. What exactly is meant by the "action on states"? Is this simply asking for an expression for $(\sqrt{E_Y} \otimes U_y) (\sigma \otimes |0 \rangle
\langle 0|)$? I don't think this is the case, since I don't get the desired expression.

I understand how to get the associated probabilities of measurement outcomes for a set of POVM elements, but I'm unclear about how this is related.
What is the action that I'm being asked about here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$M_y=\sqrt{E_y}\otimes U_y$ defines a set of Kraus operators which describes a quantum channel, i.e.,
$$\varepsilon(\rho) = \sum_y M_y\rho M_y^\dagger\ .$$
You are asked to verify that it acts as specified on the input $\sigma\otimes |0\rangle\langle 0|$.

Comment: I think I can prove that, but I'm confused about where your expression for $\varepsilon(\rho)$ comes from. I understand that $M_y \rho M_y^+$ would be the unnormalized state after measuring the density operator $\rho$. Why are we summing over all possible $y$, and why do we ignore the associated outcome probabilities? p.s. I don't see anything about Kraus operators in the text.

Comment: I think that's exactly what they mean by *"a set of operation elements defining a trace-preserving quantum operation ε"* -- a CP map (=quantum operation) with Kraus operators given by those guys.